# Simplify javascript code combined with PHP foreach

Tags: javascript, php

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let fact = -1;
  // FOREACH_STARTS_HERE
  $('table.tab-<?= $tab_id ?>').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    serverMethod: 'post',
    ajax: {
      url: 'ENDPOINT_URL',
      data: function(pdata) {
        pdata.tab = <?= $tab_id ?>;
        pdata.fact = fact;
      },
      render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text()
    },
  });

  $("#filter_1-<?= $tab_id ?>").click(function() {
    fact = -1;
    $('#filter_1-<?= $tab_id ?>').addClass("active");
    $('#filter_2-<?= $tab_id ?>').removeClass('active');
    $('#filter_3-<?= $tab_id ?>').removeClass('active');
    $('table.tab-<?= $tab_id ?>').DataTable().ajax.reload();
  });

  $("#filter_2-<?= $tab_id ?>").click(function() {
    fact = 0;
    $('#filter_2-<?= $tab_id ?>').addClass("active");
    $('#filter_1-<?= $tab_id ?>').removeClass('active');
    $('#filter_3-<?= $tab_id ?>').removeClass('active');
    $('table.tab-<?= $tab_id ?>').DataTable().ajax.reload();
  });

  $("#filter_3-<?= $tab_id ?>").click(function() {
    fact = 1;
    $('#filter_3-<?= $tab_id ?>').addClass("active");
    $('#filter_1-<?= $tab_id ?>').removeClass('active');
    $('#filter_2-<?= $tab_id ?>').removeClass('active');
    $('table.tab-<?= $tab_id ?>').DataTable().ajax.reload();
  });
  // FOREACH_ENDS_HERE
});
```

```html
<!-- FOREACH STARTS HERE -->
<li>
  <div>
    <button id="filter_1-<?= $tab_id ?>" class="active">Filter_1</button>
    <button id="filter_2-<?= $tab_id ?>">Filter_2</button>
    <button id="filter_3-<?= $tab_id ?>">Filter_3</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <table id="tab-<?= $tab_id ?>" class="tab-<?= $tab_id ?>">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header - 0</th>
            <th>Header - 1</th>
            <th>Header - 2</th>
            <th>Header - 3</th>
            <th>Header - 4</th>
            <th>Header - 5</th>
            <th>Header - 6</th>
            <th>Header - 7</th>
            <th>Header - 8</th>
            <th>Header - 9</th>
            <th>Header - 10</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<!-- FOREACH ENDS HERE -->
```

I have a javascript that generates multiple [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) using `foreach` for each table. I also generate several buttons and javascript functions for each table to filter them through server side.

Currently, I am using `foreach` to generate `.click` functions for additional filtering but I felt like this is not correct way of doing this. Sometimes I have up to 10 tables, which makes the following code 3 x 10 click function on single page. I made some research but couldn't find better approach.

Thanks in advance for any guidance, I feel like I am terrible with javascript :)

Comment: You are correct. It is terrible. All can be solved with a single function using delegation and a loop

Comment: Please post a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor WITHOUT PHP. Just HTML and script and we can try to save this

Comment: @mplungjan First of all thank you very much! I tried to do what you said and edited question accordingly, I had to keep some php part to demonstrate how current state of code is. Also mentioned about parts where foreach starts and ends

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you very much for response, I tried to add HTML and Javascript part with deducting PHP part to express what I am suffering from :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the script I would consider. I have not tested it, but you do not need the PHP at all in the script if you use the class

I split `filter_1-<?= $tab_id ?>` on `-` to get the tab_id

```js
$(function() {
  let fact = "0";
  $('table').each(function() {
    $(this).DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      serverMethod: 'post',
      ajax: {
        url: 'ENDPOINT_URL',
        data: function(pdata) {
          pdata.tab = $(this).attr("id");
          pdata.fact = fact;
        },
        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text()
      }
    });
  });

  $(".filter").on("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active")
    $(this).addClass("active");
    const tabID = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
    fact = $(this).data("fact");
    $(`table.tab-${tabID}`).DataTable().ajax.reload();
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" id="filter_1-<?= $tab_id ?>" data-fact="-1" class="filter active">Filter_1</button>
  <button type="button" id="filter_2-<?= $tab_id ?>" data-fact="0" class="filter">Filter_2</button>
  <button type="button" id="filter_3-<?= $tab_id ?>" data-fact="1" class="filter">Filter_3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and solution! `fact` is some variable used for filtering and retrieving data from server side. By default its `-1` on each button click it should be changed (`filter_1 = -1, filter_2 = 0, filter_3 = 1`) the value of `fact` should change and set before `ajax.reload()` part

Comment: See update. Use a data-attribute

Comment: Thanks again! I managed to get backend part work, but I have 2 issue, first `$(`table.tab-${id}`)` part, I am getting undefined error I believe ${id} should be ${tab} ? Second one is for `data-attribute` everytime I click on any button, it doesn't post the attribute since it stays `undefined`.

Comment: Yes. I now split the tabID from the id and save the fact in a common variable

Comment: Yes! now it works, and difference between my code and yours is just marvelous I really do appreciate it :) Only thing is, when I click any of the button, it executes 2 times :/

Comment: I had a missing }). Please look again

Comment: It works fine, thanks a lot for all your help and guidance. I learnt a lot from this code about optimization and better usage :)